# should i use delegate for a block return?

Tags: objective-c

I have some block that get data from server. I could see that I get error when trying to return my array from that block. Question is, what is right :

1. use delegates from the block to the other class that use it
2. don't use block,but selector method that being called when done, and I give it argument that is being filled and return.

   ```
   [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
        {
            for(PFObject *object in objects)
            {    
                PFObject *user = [object objectForKey:@"userId"];

                //can't return value to other class here ..
           }

        }];
   ```

Should I use delegate here? (is it possible?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical Cocoa way to do this would be to use a delegate with a callback. If you use selectors instead, you will still need to pass the block an instance of the object that the selector belongs to, and you lose some compile-time safety.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare a variable or a property assignable in block with __block prefix and then you can assign a value to it in the block and use everywhere you need.

Example:

```
__block NSString *string;
```

Comment: Looks like an asynchronous block, so it isn't possible to return the result from that method